# Joomla menu doesn't appear

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-template

I've a site built in Joomla 1.5, it was working good, after upgrading my server php to 5.3.3 the menu doesn't appear any more.

Comment: I feel your pain, when you upgrade something and something goes wrong

Comment: i really think it belongs to webmasters.stackexchange.com , already suggested the change

Comment: Enable error reporting (in Joomla and on your server) to see the issues. I ported a Mambo to php 5.3, so it can be done for Joomla!, you just need to know exactly what the issues are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joomla isn't compatible with PHP 5.3.3 until after Joomla v1.5.15, either upgrade Joomla or "downgrade" your PHP version.

Comment: Thanks you, I'll upgrade to higher joomla version

Answer (score 1):

In case upgrading Joomla doesn't solve the problem do the following:

1. In Joomla admin control panel, go to: Global Configuration --> Debug System and choose "yes"
2. then go to tools --> clean cache: check all the boxes and click on the "delete" icon
3. go back to your website and see the debug errors on the bottom of the screen.
4. Update this post with the error.